# RadGrid Conditional Row PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, webforms, radgrid

I have a RadGrid on the page that posts back when you click on the row, configured as the following:

```
<ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" />
</ClientSettings>
```

I'm trying to stop the postback by stopping the propagation of the event via:

```
function RowClick(sender, e) {
    var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
    var hasReport = masterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(e.get_item(), "HasReport").innerHTML;

    if (hasReport.trim() == "No") {
        e.get_domEvent().preventDefault();
        e.get_domEvent().stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

But this isn't working; the postback still happens.  I have a grid with two records, and I need it to postback only when a field has a value of "Yes", but I can't get this to work.  I'm sure it's hitting the no condition, but even after stopping propagation, the event still fires.  Any idea how to stop the postback?  I can't use RowSelecting because it never fires, since i'm posting back on row click.

Comment: I've done this before...  I'm writing up a demo and will reply shortly

Answer (score 1):

Drop the EnablePostBackOnRowClick - set that back to false.  Add a RadAjaxManager, if you don't have one already, and trigger the PostBack by hand.  Try something like this:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="ajaxMgr"></telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<script type="text/javascript">

function rowClick(sender, args) {
    var mastertable = sender.get_masterTableView();
    var id = mastertable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(args.get_item(), "Id").innerHTML;

    if (id == "1") {
        var ajaxMgr = $find("<%= ajaxMgr.ClientID %>");
        ajaxMgr.ajaxRequestWithTarget("<%= grid.UniqueID %>", id);
    }

}

</script>
```

You then need to handle the RaisePostBackEvent method on the codebehind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument)
{
     // Do something interesting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to prevent the ajax call with the `OnRequestStart` event when your condition is fulfilled. To do so, you must:

Listen to the `OnRequestStart` and return `false` if your row have been just clicked:

In your js:

```js
var myRowHaveBeenClicked = false;

function OnRequestStart(){
    if(myRowHaveBeenClicked){
        myRowHaveBeenClicked = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your ASP:

```xml
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="ajaxmanager">
    <clientevents onRequeststart="OnRequestStart" />
    .......
```

All is left to do is to set the `myRowHaveBeenClicked` flag during your rowClick function.

In your RowClick function:

```js
function RowClick(sender, e) {
    var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
    var hasReport = masterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(e.get_item(), "HasReport").innerHTML;

    myRowHaveBeenClicked = hasReport.trim() == "No";
}
```

The `RowClick` event occurs before the `RequestStart`, so, in that moment you can set a flag that indicates that postback shouldn't occur.

Is solution is far from clean or ellegant, but it works and is very simple.

Hope it helps :)